# Обратиться к одному значению тюпла

Tags: swift, tuple

// Если указать тип тюпла и обратиться по индексу, т.е. fromServer.0 , то все ок

```
let fromServer: (Int, String?, String?) = (statusCode: 250, message: “Ответ получен”, errorMessage: “Что-то пошло не так”)
print(fromServer.0)
```

// Если не указывать тип и обратиться по параметру, т.е fromServer2.statusCode , тоже всё ок

```
let fromServer2 = (statusCode: 250, message: “Ответ получен”, errorMessage: “Что-то пошло не так”)
print(fromServer2.statusCode)
```

// Но если и указать тип и обратиться по параметру, то выходит ошибка

```
let fromServer3: (Int, String?, String?) = (statusCode: 250, message: “Ответ получен”, errorMessage: “Что-то пошло не так”)
print(fromServer3.statusCode) // ОШИБКА ТУТ, но почему? И как исправить…
```

p.s. Помогите :)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: VAndrJ и MrRadix. Ваши оба ответа одиноково хорошие и помогли решить проблему, выбираю ответ VAndrJ "Лучшим" только потому, что он ответил на 4 минуты раньше :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что в третьем случае нет имен параметров, компилятор не знает что такое `statusCode`. Исправить можно так:

```
let fromServer3: (statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?) = (statusCode: 250, message: "Ответ получен", errorMessage: "Что-то пошло не так")
print(fromServer3.statusCode)
```

С tuples интересно то, что можно присваивать как tuple с неименованными параметрами tuple с именованными:

```
let response: (statusCode: Int, message: String?) = (200, "success")
```

так и наоборот:

```
let response: (Int, String?) = (statusCode: 200, message: "success")
```

при этом нельзя присвоить с разными именами параметров:

```
let response: (statusCode: Int, message: String?) = (сode: 200, body: "success")
```

И самое интересное:

```
(сode: 200, body: "success") == (statusCode: 200, message: "success") //true
```

Так что это не более чем проверка компилятора, дабы мы не допускали в подобных моментах ошибки во время написания.

Answer (score 2):

Во втором варианте вы не указываете тип переменной, после чего, присваиваете переменной тюпл вида `(statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?)`, но сразу со значениями. И Интерпретатор понимает какой тип используется для переменной.

В первом и третем варианте вы присваиваете переменной типа `(Int, String?, String?)` тюпл типа `(statusCode: Int, message: String, errorMessage: String)`, statusCode, message, errorMessage, это всего лишь ярлыки данных переменных. 
Так как эти ярлыки не заданы типу основной переменной, доступ по ним невозможен.

Для того, чтобы доступ был, нужно четко указать типу переменной эти ярлыки.

```
let fromServer3: (statusCode: Int, message: String?, errorMessage: String?) = (statusCode: 250, message: "Ответ получен", errorMessage: "Что-то пошло не так")
print(fromServer3.statusCode)
```

На скрине с плейграунда можно увидеть тип переменной вместе с ярлыками (2,3 вариант) и без (1-й вариант)

[image: скрин]